# Does Umbridge's scar prevent Harry from telling lies?

Tags: harry-potter

In the fifth year, Umbridge makes Harry write "I must not tell lies" using a Blood Quill. Eventually the message is permanently etched into Harry's skin as a scar. Does this scar prevent him from telling lies? If not what's the point?

Comment: Like does Voldemort spell prevent Peter Pettigrew into a rat or not? Or does Bill Weastley still prefer eating raw meat?

Comment: @MBEllis Did you mean to ping me? Or was that meant to go to the OP, TheMadHatter?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot oops my bad

Comment: @TheMadHatter If it would prevent Harry to tell lies she wouldn't need to use veritaserum on him

Comment: @MBEllis Doesn't she also threaten to use the Cruciatus Curse on him, or was that someone else?

Comment: @F1Krazy yes she does

Answer (score 16):

There is no evidence that it magically prevents Harry from lying.

Instead, this is a form of psychological torture. Umbridge forces Harry to write *with his own blood*, causing pain and a scar on himself. From Umbridge's point of view, this pain should become associated with lying - in other words, Harry should associate lying with pain and thus not lie in the future.

Of course, Harry was telling the truth the entire time, and Umbridge is a sadistic abuser who was more concerned with scarring - physically and mentally - Harry rather than discovering what the truth was. The point is just to cause pain, both physical and psychological, for Umbridge's enjoyment.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. It's kind of a way of saying that "I am hurting you because you lied. And if you continue I will continue too." I thinks it's more like a humane torture (not a magical spell or hex or anything)

Answer (score -1):

Two things points against a magical compulsion to lie, as opposed to her merely doing it out of cruelty and hopes of making him fear to lie to her.

The first is that she tried to use veritaserum on him after it, so she knew he could still lie.

The second is that while she is torturing him and asks him to change his story, he does not automatically and instantly tell the truth.  He could have lied and claimed that Voldemort had not returned, but *choose* to tell the truth.

Comment: The answer is self-contradictory due to the fact that TRUTH is NOT what Umbridge wants to hear from Harry. So she is not satisfied with the actual truth that he tells most of the time. but rather wants him to shut up and agree to the Ministry-approved version of the events.